# How can I disable the select2 plugin for certain select dropdowns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using the jquery select2 plugin but I want to disable it for certain select dropdowns. Is there a way to exclude select elements the plugin will be applied to?
I was thinking maybe a class on the select element to tell the plugin to ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are applying it to all selects via:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('select').select2();
</script>
```

There are a few ways you could solve it, but the easiest would be to add a class to the selects you want to be styled And only call the `select2()` on those:

- Add the class `addStyling` to your selects to be styled
- Initialize them with `$('select.addStyling').select2();`

Comment: I'm working on a huge project with hundreds of selects so it's easier to specify what I don't want to be applied to as there are only going to be a few of these. Good idea though

Comment: Do it in reverse then :)  Add a class to the ones not to be styled and use the not selector.

Comment: yeah $('select:not(.whatever)').select2()

Answer (score 6):

```
$('select').not('.yourExcludeClass').select2();
```

Here's a [link to the docs for $.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Answer (score 2):

While just not calling `.select2()` on the elements which you don't want to be dropdown works, you might want to disable Select2 *after* you've already initialized it.

In order to do this, you have two options

- Visually disable it like you would a standard `<select>` by calling `$("select").prop("disabled", true)`.
- "Destroy" Select2 so it goes back to looking like a standard dropdown by calling `$("select").select2("destroy")`.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable it using -

```
$('select').select2("enable",false);
```

using JQuery.

Comment: Great solution when you don't have control over the select2() create function, for example when you're working with a theme / template that has select2 build-in. Thanks!